# Does PostgreSQL have a feature to update the "internal" constraint names and whatnot?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

This always happens:

1. I design (create) a series of tables with PKs, FKs, UNIQUEs and sometimes indexes. pgAdmin 4 seems to add/encourage indexes added when making FKs. I never pick a name myself, but allow it to pick whatever name it wants, which is based on the table name and column names.
2. I make changes, such as renaming tables and/or columns.
3. Those constraints now have annoyingly outdated names. Renaming them is anything but straight-forward and apparently requires me to delete and then recreate them, which often is impossible due to data loss or errors preventing them from being deleted.

Is there some way to automatically rename them all so that they match the current table/column/etc. names?

I don't think I have ever directly referred to those constraints by name, so it would not break anything in my application code.

I frankly don't even understand why they need names to begin with, but it's very annoying when they are called things which are no longer relevant.

Comment: Please clarify point 3 on Data loss or Errors: sample code would be helpful.  Dropping and Recreating Indexes should never cause loss of data.

Comment: "*which often is impossible due to data loss or errors preventing them from being deleted.*" does not really make sense. How would deleting (and re-creating) a foreign key constraint cause data **loss**? Are you doing those two steps in a single transaction?

Comment: There is no better way than a lot of `ALTER ` statements. `psql`'s `\gexex` might help. But I'd recommend living with the original names.